# SharePoint list - open attachment without downloading them

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, attachments, pdf

Has anyone solved the problem of how to open attachments without downloading directly in the browser?

I tried everything, Chrome, Edge, Addons, nothing works. The attached PDFs are downloaded first and then opened. How do I open the PDF directly in my browser?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For List item attachments**:

Use below settings to open PDF files "in browser" by default in Google chrome:

[image]

Follow steps given in this article: [Change the Default PDF Viewer in Chrome](https://www.civicengagecentral.civicplus.help/hc/en-us/articles/360008064353-Change-the-Default-PDF-Viewer-in-Chrome)

You can find similar settings and steps for:

- Microsoft Edge browser at: https://knowledge.kofax.com/MFD_Productivity/Power_PDF/How_To/Prevent_Google_Chrome_or_Edge_from_opening_PDF_files
- Mozilla Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/985483

---

**For Document Library files**

Try using **Open** > **Open in browser** option from command bar at the top or from context menu.

**Command Bar**:

[image]

**Context Menu**:

[image]

Comment: this option is for Library, my problem is in the Sharepoint list, where PDF is a attachment.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on PDF documents setting in the different browsers.

In the Edge, go to Settings -> Cookies and site permissions -> PDF documents -> Enable Open PDFs to last viewed location when you reopen files.

[image]

Comment: i found only solution, when i create flow, to get URI from attachment and paste URI to different column instead of Attachment. After that i can open PDF without download.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.